# Is this the right way to check if a table exists before creating it?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.tables 
        WHERE [name] = N'MyTableName' AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'MyDataBaseName'))
BEGIN

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTableName]
(
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [Index_No] [varchar](50) NULL   
) 
END
```

I am using the above T-SQL to check if a table exists in my database and if it does not exist i create. I am however wonder if this is the right way of doing it or is there better recomended approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using a bit smaller query to do that:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##Product', 'U') IS  NULL 
CREATE TABLE ##Product (DataTypeID INT NULL, 
            ProductID INT  NOT NULL,
            CountryCodeID INT NOT NULL)
ELSE TRUNCATE TABLE ##Product;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a logical error in your query, namely the `object_id` column in `sys.tables` is not related to the database (it is the table's object_id from the `sys.objects` catalog view).

OBJECT_ID('DatabaseName') will evaulate to `NULL` unless there is a table (an object, not just a table) named exactly as the database itself, but in this case, you will retrieve that object's `object_id` instead of the database's.

Because of the above two reasons, your `IF` statement will always evaulates to true. (The query will not find any match, so the `EXISTS` will evaulate to false)

[Almazini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2240008/almazini)'s answer is a pretty good approach. I recommend to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have simple creation statements, then condition like

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.TableName', 'U') IS NULL BEGIN
    ...statements....
END
```

will be good enough. If your script is more complex, there is another approach:

```
-- If object exists we disable scripts execution
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.TableName', 'U') IS NOT NULL SET NOEXEC ON

...you can even create triggers/functions/procedures here...

-- Enable script execution
SET NOEXEC OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE name='MyTableName' AND type='U')
   BEGIN
       CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTableName]
       (
        [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
        [FirstName] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
        [LastName] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
        [Index_No] [varchar](50) NULL  
       ) 
   END
```